# How to determine the network unavailability in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, android-internet

I want to show alert that connection not available in my android application.

I am calling some rest request in my application. To check this network unavailability scenario I manually disconnect my wifi in my laptop (I am testing in simulator) .

Code where I call service is here

```
resp = client.execute(httpPostRequest);
```

and here I am catching exception

```
catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            //assertTrue(e.getLocalizedMessage(), false);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //assertTrue(e.getLocalizedMessage(), false);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //assertTrue(e.getLocalizedMessage(), false);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and when I get exception I try to get the status of the device network connection with 
this function

```
public boolean IsInternetConnectted()
    {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        conMgr = null;
        if (i == null)
            return false;
        if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
        if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
        return true;        
    }
```

even if wi-fi is disconnected my simulator return true from this function.

How to resolve this situaltion??

Comment: To Toggle cell networking on/off in emulator press F8 and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found that same error in my Emulator...
But Try your Code on Mobile Device this code Run Perfectly and not coming any error in real Device...

Answer (score 4):

use this snippet:

```
 // added as an instance method to an Activity
boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable() {  
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();     
    if (info == null) return false;
    State network = info.getState();
    return (network == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || network == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello Please Check Following answer :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217676/how-to-check-the-real-internet-connected-in-android/13217956#13217956
```

But I want to suggest you that it is recommended that you should test the connection code in real device rather Emulator. Because emulator some time not giving accurate output.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static Boolean checknetwork(Context mContext) {

    NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) 
    {

        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
        // disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return true;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        boolean state=false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


        NetworkInfo wifiNetwork =
            cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (wifiNetwork != null) {
            state=wifiNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
             }

            NetworkInfo mobileNetwork =
            cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (mobileNetwork != null) {
            state=mobileNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
            state=activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

            }

            return state;
      }
```

For Better Results, Check on Real Device..

Answer (score 0):

Send HttpRequest and check then response code you are getting if its `200`
 you are connected to internet else you are not and can notify the  user accordingly

Answer (score 0):

To Check Internet Connectivity

```
 public class CheckNetwork {


private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();



public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
{
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null)
    {
         Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
         //Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", 1000);
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(info.isConnected())
        {
            Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
 }
```

In your Activity Class

```
        if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(YourActivity.this))
             {
               //your studd
             }
```

Use f7 to disconnect and connect in emulator. I am not sure. Google it.
Alternatively you can use broadcast receiver or service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (info != null);
}
```